# Solvability of the quintic by radicals - missing step?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

A theorem due to Galois asserts that a polynomial $f\in F[x]$ can be solved by radicals iff. the Galois group of $f$ is a solvable group.

In my lecture notes as a corollary I have the following: The general equation of degree $n$ cannot be solved by radicals if $n\geq 5$.

The proof of this corollary is just this: $S_n$ is not a solvable group if $n\geq 5$.

My question is this: why are we dealing with $S_n$ here? The Galois group of $f$ is the Galois group $G$ of its splitting field $F(\alpha_1,\dots\alpha_n)$. Then $G$ embeds as a subgroup of $S_n$ since it acts by permuting the roots $\alpha_i$. Why do we have that $G=S_n$?

Comment: Some polynomials of degree $5$ have Galois group $S_n$ (in fact, in a sense that can be made precise, almost all of them do), so there are some polynomials of degree $5$ not solvable in radicals. So, in contrast to the case of polynomials of degree $\leq 4$, there is no general expression for the roots of a degree-$5$ polynomial in terms of radicals.

Comment: @TravisWillse This is true over $\mathbb{Q}$. But OP asks about the general equation, over a general field. For example, every specific polynomial is trivially solvable by radicals over $\mathbb{C}$. However, by the general polynomial over $F$ we mean the polynomial $x^n+T_nx^{n-1}+...+T_2x+T_1$ over the field of rational functions $F(T_1,T_2,...,T_ n)$. It requires some work (best way is to use the theory of transcendence degree) to show that the Galois group of this polynomial over $F(T_1,...,T_n)$ is $S_n$. So the "general equation" indeed has no solution in radicals if $n\geq 5$.

Comment: @Mark Ah, you're right, I was thinking of the classical case $\Bbb Q$. Consider filling in the details and promoting your comment to a full answer.

Comment: @TravisWillse And to support you a bit, many authors then take $F=\Bbb Q$ anyway and even more questioners here assume it implicitly without saying. Indeed, the typical statement is:"The general equation of degree $n$ cannot be solved by radicals if $n\geq 5$" - with no reference to the field.

Comment: My impression is that none of the above comments address my question. My question is about a missing technical step in an outline of a proof.